# Convert Series to list of dictionaries in pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary

I have a Series of the form `["A","B","B","C","A"]`.

I am counting the frequency of each unique element using `pandas.Series.value_counts` which also returns a Series: `["A":2,"B":2,"C":1]`

I want to convert this Series into a list of dictionaries `[{A:2},{B:2},{C:1}]`. However, neither `to_dict` nor `to_records` is giving me the desired result. What's an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think any type-conversion method in Pandas for Series or DataFrames will produce exactly the output you're after.

You might simply have to adjust the result of `to_dict()` with a list comprehension:

```
>>> counts = pd.value_counts(series).to_dict()
>>> [{u: v} for (u, v) in counts.iteritems()]
[{'A': 2}, {'C': 1}, {'B': 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you need `counter`

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> [ {x:y} for x,y in Counter(["A","B","B","C","A"]).items() ]
[{'A': 2}, {'C': 1}, {'B': 2}]
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question seems to request a list of dictionaries, not a single dictionary.

Comment: @ajcr thanks to inform me, i dedn't seen the OP clearly